# Why is Android Studio not showing possible properties of a widget?

Tags: android-studio, properties, widget

In a couple of resource with Android Studio I have seen people typing a widget's name and after closing the parenthesis a list of possible properties was appearing appear above the widet as show in the screenshot. However, I am not getting this displayed. Can someone shine some light on what needs to be set in order see this list?

[how it is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQbwE.png)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this: Just press CTRL and hoover with the mouse pointer over it.